# How to load the custom Model in Opencart

Tags: php, classloader, opencart

I have created the one custom Module in Opencart.

The details of that:

**Controller**: file named block.php in admin/controller/custom/block.php

**View**  : file named block.tpl in admin/view/template/custom/block.tpl

**Model** : file named block.php in admin/model/custom/block.php

I have successfully configured permissions.

[image]

When I load this model in Controller means, I got the following error..

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\shirtrecipe\admin\controller\custom\block.php on line 11
```

**Controller Code:**

```
<?php

class ControllerCustomBlock extends Controller
{
public function index() {


    $this->language->load('custom/block');

    $this->model->load('custom/block'); /* doesnt load this model */

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
            ...
            ...
```

**Model Code:**

```
<?php

class ModelCustomBlock extends Model
{

public function get_demo_block() {

    $sql = "select demo_block_img from oc_block where id=1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->row;

}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change :

`$this->model->load('custom/block');`

To:

`$this->load->model('custom/block');`

Have a nice day !!